# roll back OS X app versions without full system install

Tags: macos, upgrade

I had to roll back my OS X version, and ended up with High Sierra (factory install, then some security updates). But when I imported my settings from Time Machine, I managed to end up with numerous programs that require a later OS X version, and will not open. These include Notes, ctivity Monitor, Terminal, and various dyn libraries needed by other programs. How can I bring apps and libraries **back** to the OS version I have (i.e., High Sierra)? I do not have a usable backup of the apps folder for this version. Is there an alternative to doing another full instal of High Sierra?

I plan to upgrade to Catalina next, but the catalina installer is among the apps that run but fail, with a complaint about incomptible versions.

Comment: Basically you can'\t you need the versions of the apps that run on the older OS. In this case it might be better to sort out the issue that made you roll back - why did you have to do that

Comment: Reason: Essential third-party app that does not run on Big Sur. My goal here is exactly to restore the versions of the apps that run on the older OS -- sorry if that was unclear. Is there a way to do that without reinstalling the entire OS again?

Comment: Don‘t restore applications from backup then but reinstall them from the App Store.

Comment: @nohillside, sounds great but how does one install standard system applications from the App Store? I just searched for Textedit, Activity Monitor, Terminal ... I don't see any of the standard apps on offer.

Comment: Not at all, they get installed with the OS

Comment: Ok so i do have to reinstall the OS, there is no way to repair the apps to bring them back to their fresh-installed state?

Comment: What is the difference between a factory install, then some security updates, of High Sierra and a full system install of High Sierra? Can I assume a  full system install of High Sierra is where you do not use time machine?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that. I don't care about the difference between the two scenarios you describe, I was trying to avoid having to do another clean install.

Comment: Update: Since nobody happened by with an answer, I gave up and did a fresh reinstall of the OS. Would still be interested in learning if there is a better way (as would others, I'm sure).